# Is there a way to update a variable outside an event listener using that listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a situation where I have a variable in cloud storage, that I am fetching asynchronously every time I want to do something with it. Currently the code looks like this:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
        // Fetch example_variable from storage, then
        // Do things with example_variable...
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() {
        // Fetch example_variable from storage, then
        // Do things with example_variable...
});
```

Since fetching the `example_variable` from the cloud every time the events trigger (it can happen more than a dozen times per minute) is very inefficient, I was thinking about restructuring it like this:

```js
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() { // Everytime the cloud variable changes
        // Fetch example_variable from storage, then
        // set example_variable to what I fetched.
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
        // Do things with example_variable...
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() {
        // Do things with example_variable...
});
```

My first thought was to create new listeners inside of the storage update listener (and close the old ones), but the Chrome Extension documentation [directly warns against this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#listeners).

I *could* use globally-scoped variables, but that seems incredibly janky and inelegant.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Continually adding and removing the listeners is definitely a no-go. I think you already answered the title of your question: use a variable outside of the scope of the listener. What's so janky or inelegant about that?

Comment: If you don't want global variables, you could wrap all the listeners in a block or IIFE and declare local variables in that block/IIFE.

Comment: @skyline3000 I just want to make sure I'm using best practice. I'm relatively new to JS, and I don't want to be kicking myself later about something. My main concern with a global variable is that I'm defining a lot of functions with similar variable names, but I suppose using a different name for it would work just as well.